# Difference between Alert.Authenticate and Alert.setCredentials

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between `"driver.switchTo().alert().Authenticate()"` and `"driver.switchTo().alert().setCredentails()"`? Both use the Interface Credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authenticate invokes **Accept** after setting credentials. It could be found in sources.

```
    public void setCredentials(Credentials credentials) {
        if(!(credentials instanceof UserAndPassword)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported credentials: " + credentials);
        } else {
            UserAndPassword userAndPassword = (UserAndPassword)credentials;
            RemoteWebDriver.this.execute("setAlertCredentials", ImmutableMap.of("username", userAndPassword.getUsername(), "password", userAndPassword.getPassword()));
        }
    }


    public void authenticateUsing(Credentials credentials) {
        this.setCredentials(credentials);
        this.accept();
    }
```